# Копирование только указанных полей объекта в одну операцию

Tags: javascript

Есть ли способ поверхностного копирования в новый объект только указанных полей другого объекта в одну операцию (условно говоря), чтобы не перечислять поля дважды?

Например что-то вроде этого (псевдокод):

```
let partialCopy{ nameOne, nameTwo, goodName } = originalObject;
```

Эта задача легко получается через деструктуризацию, но при этом приходится перечислять поля дважды, что повышает вероятность ошибок и выглядит громоздко при длинных списках:

```
let { nameOne, nameTwo, goodName } = originalObject,
    partialCopy = { nameOne, nameTwo, goodName };
```

Примечание 1: originalObject в примере может иметь много свойств, а нужно взять только указанные из него.

Примечание 2: функции возвращают непонятный тип в случае typescript, поэтому менее желательны. Если решение - это функция, то она должна вывести тип получаемого объекта, как это легко получается в примере с деструктуризацией.

Comment: кто мешает сделать какой-нить `Object.prototype.partialCopy = function(fields){ return fields.reduce((res, f) => (res[f] = this[f], res), {}); }` ?

Comment: @teran , как IDE выведет тип возвращаемого объекта?

Comment: я откуда знаю, что там ваша IDE умеет. про нее в вопросе вообще ничего не было.

Comment: Извините, слабо акцентировал второе примечание.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку нет хорошего ответа на js пока, сделал на typescript в качестве решения с сохранением типов такую функцию:

```
objectPartialCopy<From, T extends (keyof From)[]>( obj: From, ...keys: T ): Pick<From, T[number]> {
    let resultObj: Pick<From, T[number]> = {} as any;
    
    keys.forEach(( key: keyof From )=>{
        resultObj[key] = obj[key];
    });
    
    return resultObj;
}
```

Пользоваться можно так:

```
let copy = objectPartialCopy( window, 'innerWidth', 'innerHeight' );
```

Преимущества данного подхода показаны на следующих скриншотах:

Подсказки ключей в IDE:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подсвечивает неверные ключи в IDE:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верный тип скопированного объекта (тип не теряется):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При присвоении неверного типа ожидаемо ругается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Недостатки - это всё-таки функция, а не простой оператор или подход, и может не поддерживаться в IDE для js.