# Деструктуризация. Из объекта в объект

Tags: javascript, деструктурирующее-присваивание

Дано - объект с множеством полей. Мне нужен новый объект, который бы содержал в себе лишь пару значений из основного. Можно ли это сделать с помощью деструктуризации.

Я привык делать так. Но приходится 2 раза писать одни и те же названия ключей.

```js
const base = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}

const { a, b } = base;

const target = {
  a,
  b
}
console.log(target)
```

Comment: не, не получится(

Comment: Задавал аналогичный вопрос, и пока решения нет, - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1211960/347472